# Bone Roll disturbing Mesh Rotation in Pose Mode

Tags: rigging, edit-mode, weight-painting, pose-mode

When, I done may `Weight Paints` my Edit Bones are Like this:
[image]

But, When I'm creating control bones, I realized that I need to change the `roll` of my leg bones, But this is disturbing Mesh Rotation in `Pose Mode` Like this:
[image]

Applying `Pose to Rest Pose` is not working.
I think, I need to retarget weight paint, does anyone know?

Comment: Hello could you please share your file (just the armature)? https://blend-exchange.com/

Comment: Thanks @moonboots, Problem is Solved, Actually I'm using `DEF_` Bones on top of `Target` Bones.

Comment: Oh OK great then ;)

Answer (score 0):

The Problem is Solved, I'm using `DEF_` Bones on top of `Target` Bones.
Next time, I will make sure checking layers, before asking a question.